# Applying a filter on an input sequence in matlab

Tags: matlab, convolution, filtering

Given a input sequence $x = {x_1, ... x_n}$ and a filter with l elements $h = [h_1, ..., h_l]$ with l < n. We want to filter the input sequence with the specified filter.

My first thought was to compute the convolution between $x$ and $h$:

$y = \sum_{k=0}^{l-1} x(k) h(n - k)$

For this to work I'll have to pad x with zeros.

`x = [ zeros(1, l) x zeros(1, l - 1)];`

And then

`for i = 1:length(x) - 2 
     y(k) = h * x(k:k + l)';
 end`

Is this the right approach for this problem ?

Comment: you forget to "flip" `h`. Also, there's a "convolve" function.

Comment: Hey, You're right h should be $h = [h_l, ..., h_1]$. Other than that the approach is right, yes ?

Comment: mathematically, yes, I guess. But please, never ever write such matlab code in practice: Matlab's interpreter is stupidly slow, and there's an existing function for convolution, so aside from the "finger practice", this code shouldn't exist.